# how to get a JSON data file to output data on the html page

Tags: json

what i'm trying to do is output the JSON values to my page where the ID on my html mockup matches the ID of the JSON object:

this is my JSON file and score = the % so 10 = 10%:

```
{
"Sidekicks": [
    {
        "Id": 1098,     // this will be the sidekick "Rose Tyler(Dr Who)" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 20     
    },
    {
        "Id": 1099,     // this will be the sidekick "Dr Watson" but this name can change at any time;
        "Score": 10
    }

]
```

}

and on my html page where the ID's must match the JSON it looks like this:

```
<div id="sidekicks" class="side-kick-holder">
                <ul>
                    <li>

                        <div id="1098" class="hit super-box shuv-down-10" >

                            <h4>Rose Tyler <span class="thin">(Dr Who)</span>
                            <div class="circle"><img id="red-tick" class="change-img" data-alt-src="img/circle-hover.png" src="img/circle-grey.png" alt="circle"></div>
                            </h4>

                            <div class="line-grey"><span class="red-line-fill"></span></div>
                        </div>

                    </li>
               </ul>
</div>
```

the value has to fill the `class="red-line-fill"`

my jquery:

```
 $(document).ready( function(){
        $.getJSON( "json/sidekicks.json", function(obj){
            $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                $("div#sidekicks").append("")
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you okay with using jQuery? Also, we don't need to see your CSS as it's unrelated to the question.

Comment: well im half and half with jQuery. i need some advice this is for a project thats due tomorrow and i cant seem to wrap my head around how im going to get the red line to fill up on page load with the % of the score in the JSON data file. sorry about the css im a bit of a noob

Comment: Loading data from a Json file is a different question than getting the CSS formatting how you want it. One question at a time!

Comment: i know it starts with something like this:

Comment: well i just put the css there to show how it should look. i need the data to load from the JSON file ill update my code quick to show you how i started my JQuery code but i got lost after "append"

Comment: @mason i just updated my code see the last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Its just a guess, I haven't used JQ in a long time and I'm just writing an educated guess. Without a working environment to test it in I can't guarantee much.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.getJSON( "json/sidekicks.json", function(obj){
        $.each(obj.Sidekicks, function(key, value){
            $('div#' + value.Id + '.red-line-fill').text(value.Score);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: ill try it out and let you know, it looks right. problem is when view the developers tools in crome to see if the json file loads it responds saying No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. what does this mean

Comment: That means that the rules of the Internet say that what you are trying to do is prohibited, if you are accessing content off your hard drive you should be able to get around this but running chrome with a flag: google "allow-file-access-from-files"

Comment: More specifically I think that error pertains to cross site scripting prohibition. The easiest way to get around that is to dispatch your json from the same domain as that you accessed the html file from. If you are trying to load json from some other person's website, you are going to have a bad time from my understanding. You can look into it further by googling "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Comment: To maybe be more clear, "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is a header that the server sends to tell browsers NOT to use this content if its trying to be accessed from somewhere besides its own domain. *Disclaimer, This is all from memory, google can tell you more :) *

Comment: +10 thats some heavy-duty information sir, thanks for that. another thing if i allow the access-control then how will the json object know that for every score value if the score is 20 then it must add 20% to the red bar

Comment: and also would it help if i rather made a JSONP rather than JSON

Comment: i got it to work but the json file is not pulling in the values